Alternatives to the AHI metric for sleep apnea?
The commonly accepted metric for diagnosing sleep apnea and determining its severity is the apnea-hypopnea index (AHI).
AHI turns out to be a grossly misleading metric, though, for the following reasons:

it is an average (an index), but averages and indices are not applicable to biology: e.g. two oxygen drops of 5% are not equivalent to one oxygen drop of 10%;
it does not take into account the severity of apnea episodes in terms of oxygen drops, as far as PAP machines are concerned;
it does not take into account sleep architecture (neither anomalies in the sleep phase patterns, nor distribution of events over the different phases);
the values for defining apnea and hypopnea events are not standardized among manufacturers of either PAP machines or diagnostic devices;
it does not take into account flow limitations;
it does not take into account respiratory effort-related arousals (RERAs);
it does not take into account the patient's feeling of sleepiness and exhaustion on wake-up and throughout the day;
it does not take into account dream patterns and dream pathologies (intensity and vividness of dreams, dream recall, false awakenings, etc);
it does not take into account presence and severity of sleep inertia.

This has been acknowledged by the scientific community in papers, such as:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8889969/ <Pitfalls of AHI system of severity grading in obstructive sleep apnoea - PMC>
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8034221/ <The AHI: not all that it’s cracked up to be - PMC>


Some attempts to get over AHI so far:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5070750/ <Effective Apnea-Hypopnea Index (“Effective AHI”): A New Measure of Effectiveness for Positive Airway Pressure Therapy - PMC>
respiratory disturbance index (RDI) - https://academic.oup.com/sleep/article/45/Supplement_1/A324/6592987 <0743 Should We Use AHI or RDI to Diagnose Obstructive Sleep Apnea? | SLEEP | Oxford Academic>
https://www.atsjournals.org/doi/10.1164/rccm.202301-0109OC <Ventilatory Burden as a Measure of Obstructive Sleep Apnea Severity Is Predictive of Cardiovascular and All-Cause Mortality | American Journal of Respiratory and Critical Care Medicine>
https://openres.ersjournals.com/content/7/1/00928-2020 <Evaluation of a multicomponent grading system for obstructive sleep apnoea: the Baveno classification | European Respiratory Society>
https://erj.ersjournals.com/content/62/6/2300828 <Hypoxic burden to guide CPAP treatment allocation in patients with obstructive sleep apnoea: a post hoc study of the ISAACC trial | European Respiratory Society>


Do you know of any other approaches to measuring and tracking severity of sleep apnea, either quantitatively or qualitatively, even if not clinically researched or validated?
